# How to play Mine Little Pony Mod in Minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have Minecraft 1.12.2

[image]

I'd like to use the [Mine Little Pony Mod with LiteLoader](http://www.minelittlepony-mod.com/installation/) so I downloaded [liteloader](http://www.liteloader.com/download#snapshot_11220) for 1.1.2, made a `mods` folder in `..../Library/Application Support/minecraft/mods` and inside placed `mod-minelittlepony-1.12.2.1-mc1.12.2.litemod`.  I selected liteloader and clicked play but I still see the original game.

[image]

I noticed that a new folder `1.12.2` was created inside mods so I also copied the `mod-minelittlepony-1.12.2.1-mc1.12.2.litemod` there but it didn't help.

Is it possible to play this mod with this version of Minecraft?  Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: That sounds like how you would install mods with Forge. I don't know if that's the way for LiteLoader, too. Do other mods work that way? Does it appear in the mod list? What does this button on the bottom right in your 1.12.2 screenshot do?

Comment: @Fabian Thanks for the comments.  I'll need to check things out after work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure this one out either but if you go to the skins you can select a skin and then you'll at least be a pony of your choice. You do this from the Minecraft start screen after you select liteloader and click play. Then on the right side you'll see an icon that looks like a pair of pants. Click that then browse for a pony skin inside the Minecraft mod folder and you can do that. The only way I was able to get to a map that looked like I expected... my little pony style is to join one of the few via multiplayer join server.

There's https://poniarcade.com and http://mc.ponyconcordia.com

I hope this helps a bit as I spent two days trying to get to a place that looked more like my little pony for my daughter.